# Combining rows in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Let me start by saying I'm very new to SSRS.

I have built a report that displays data in a table such as below

```
            Test1 | Test2 | Test3
----------------------------------
Patient A | 1:00  |       |
----------------------------------
Patient A |       | 1:30  |
----------------------------------
Patient A |       |       | 1:30
----------------------------------
Patient B | 2:00  |       |
----------------------------------
Patient B |       |       | 2:00
```

I'd like to combine the rows with common patient IDs so that it looks like this:

```
          | Test1 | Test2 | Test3
----------------------------------
Patient A | 1:00  | 1:30  | 1:30
----------------------------------
Patient B | 2:00  |       | 2:00
```

Is there an easy way to make that happen?

Comment: Assuming this data is coming from some SQL query, you can also update SQL query to group and return the result in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. All you need to do is edit the row group properties and set it to group by the patient ID. By default there is a row group called "Details" this is not grouped by anything and so it shows one row for each row in your dataset. By adding the grouping, you can override that.

For the times to show up, you may need to add an aggregate expression around them such as a `Max`. This will make sure that you still see the correct time for each intersection of patients and test numbers. So the expression would look something like this:

```
=Max(Fields!Time.Value)
```

This same expression will work for all the cells as the groups expand.

Comment: When I give this a try I am left with a single row for each patient (which is good) but I'm only getting a single test in each row as well.  So if patient A has 3 tests, only the first test is showing up in that row

Comment: If there are always 3 tests on the report, those can be separate columns. If you want it to be dynamic, use a column group by test number (or test name). This will ensure that you get columns for every test in the dataset when you run the report.